# Jquery slideshow through divs and pause on hover

Tags: jquery, css, mouseevent

I have a slide show, is not woking as wanted atm,

- on mouseover, mouseenter pause - addClass('current hover'), removing the previous (current)
- on mouseleave keep going through the divs adding and removing class current

http://jsfiddle.net/ead6ekhz/

```
var timer;

$("#slideshow > div:gt(0)").addClass('current');

$("#slideshow").mouseenter(function () {
    if (timer) {
        clearInterval(timer).addClass('hovered');
    }
}).mouseleave(function () {
    timer = setInterval(function () {
        $("#slideshow > div:first")
            .removeClass('current')
            .next()
            .addClass('current')
            .end()
            .appendTo("#slideshow");
    }, 2000);
}).mouseleave();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well, I'm not a JS GURU like people around here on stackoverflow, but from what I understood, you should implement something like this:
Actually probably is better with `mouseover`

```
function slideSwitch() {
    var $active = $('#slideshow a.active');
    if ($active.length === 0) $active = $('#slideshow a:last');
    var $next = $active.next().length ? $active.next() : $('#slideshow a:first');

    $active.addClass('last-active');

    $next.css({
        //add something here
    })
        .addClass('active')
        .animate({
        //add something here
    }, 1000, function () {
        $active.removeClass('active last-active');
    });
}
$(function () {
    var interval = setInterval(slideSwitch, 1000);

    $('#slideshow a').hover(function () {
        clearInterval(interval);
        $('.active').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');


    }, function () {
        interval = setInterval(slideSwitch, 1000);
    });


});
```

Demo:
http://jsfiddle.net/pgov2h2k/